# CiviRule not triggering

Tags: civirules

I am trying to setup a rule to notify donors and staff when a payment fails, but for some reason I can't get the trigger to work.  Trigger is "contribution added" and condition is "contribution status = failed" (we use moneris for online payments and it does add a contribution record with status failed)

In the email message there are 2 "from" fields.  I can manually type an email in one, the other is a drop-down list.  However, only one email shows in the drop-down when we have dozens saved in the FROM email addresses setup.

[image]

Comment: would this be a useful alternative? https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.incompletepaymentalert

Comment: I would try adding a failed contribution manually to see if that triggers the rule. It may be that the contribution is first being created and then set to failed after or something like that.

Comment: @LarsSG you are right - I manually added a failed contribution and it triggered the civirule. I think if I change my trigger to "contribution is changed" it might work

Comment: @petednz-fuzion thanks, but I would like to notify the donor (especially for recurring donations that fail) as well as notify staff

Comment: that could be something we could add in as an option on the above extension if there was a bit of funding.

Comment: @erin - did changing the rule to 'Contribution is changed' work?  I expect it would since contributions should be initially created as 'status = pending' and then updated.  If that works, please add it as answer

Answer (score 2):

Changing the trigger to 'contribution is changed' seems to have worked.